# Routes to a public images folder not firing

Tags: laravel, routes

I have the following route in laravel 5.2

```
Route::get('images/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    if($filename)
    {
        return redirect('/home');
    }    
});
```

If a person enters the following url: www.mydomain.com/images/image_abc123.jpg, I hope that it would be redirected to www.mydomain.com/home. But the route is not triggering and goes to show the image instead.

Any advise? Thank you!

Edit: here is my .htaccess the default of laravel 5.2 under /public directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried Defining Middleware?

Comment: Yes sir, I have. It's not triggered too. It's that or i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: how did you do it? can u show me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright! public folder is named public for a reason!
to fix this you have to put those images in the storage folder (thats what the storage folder is if you ever wondered)

```
Storage/app
```

so they dont exist in public folder anymore and people can't reach them unless 
you do this

```
Route::get('images/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
     // get the image named $slug from storage and display it
    // Something like (not sure)

       $image = File::get('images/' . $filename . '.jpg');

        return response()->make($image, 200, ['content-type' => 'image/jpg']);

});
```

what you want to achieve = preventing some or all people from accesing a file
what the answer does =prevents the files from being public unless you serve theme using a method
i hope everything is clear

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of your webserver. The common default is typically like this.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name cards.foo *.cards.foo;
        root /var/www/cards/public;

        index index.php;
        include php.conf;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
}
```

Notice the `try_files` directive. This is telling the webserver:

1. If the request is an extant file, open it.
2. If the request is an extant directory, index it.
3. Else, pass the directory as an argument to the /index.php.

So, on the first pass, "Does that file exist?", it says "yes" and bypasses PHP 100%. You will want to change that.

Comment: Thank you Josh. Your answer makes sense. I am using the default .htaccess of laravel 5.2, how do i modify it?

Comment: Check out the source code. You'll want to remove the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. Be aware this will break all requests for CSS and JS too. If you need more advice on editing .htaccess files, you should make another SO question. https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-basic/blob/master/public/.htaccess